# What are the CSV headers in Outlook contact export?

Tags: windows, csv, outlook

I need to generate a contacts list in CSV format, as if exported by Outlook. But I don't have Outlook (or Windows) to check what exact headers it generates.

What I'm asking for is a sample of a CSV contacts file as exported by Microsoft Office Outlook Contacts (a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578971/outlook-contact-export-to-csv-format-differences) indicated that different versions produce identical output, so the exact version of Outlook is not important). The first line of it would be enough. It would also be nice to know for sure what the line-endings are (\n or \r\n).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here's what I got from Outlook 2010:

```
"Title","First Name","Middle Name","Last Name","Suffix","Company","Department","Job Title","Business Street","Business Street 2","Business Street 3","Business City","Business State","Business Postal Code","Business Country/Region","Home Street","Home Street 2","Home Street 3","Home City","Home State","Home Postal Code","Home Country/Region","Other Street","Other Street 2","Other Street 3","Other City","Other State","Other Postal Code","Other Country/Region","Assistant's Phone","Business Fax","Business Phone","Business Phone 2","Callback","Car Phone","Company Main Phone","Home Fax","Home Phone","Home Phone 2","ISDN","Mobile Phone","Other Fax","Other Phone","Pager","Primary Phone","Radio Phone","TTY/TDD Phone","Telex","Account","Anniversary","Assistant's Name","Billing Information","Birthday","Business Address PO Box","Categories","Children","Directory Server","E-mail Address","E-mail Type","E-mail Display Name","E-mail 2 Address","E-mail 2 Type","E-mail 2 Display Name","E-mail 3 Address","E-mail 3 Type","E-mail 3 Display Name","Gender","Government ID Number","Hobby","Home Address PO Box","Initials","Internet Free Busy","Keywords","Language","Location","Manager's Name","Mileage","Notes","Office Location","Organizational ID Number","Other Address PO Box","Priority","Private","Profession","Referred By","Sensitivity","Spouse","User 1","User 2","User 3","User 4","Web Page"
```

Items of note:

1. Line endings are `\r\n`.
2. File is ASCII, not Unicode.

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my evening and my marriage.

Comment: I can confirm the same headers with Outlook 2016