# Get outlook address book list using php curl?

Tags: php, javascript, curl

I would like to import all contacts from outlook address book. I want to know is there any way to bring all the contacts from outlook using php. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try to export all the contacts to a csv file.

1. File | Import and Export...
2. Export a file
3. Select comma seperated values
4. Select the Contacts folder
5. Save file to desktop

If you have done this, you could upload this file to php and parse the csv file format. An example of the outlook csv format can be found [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847596/what-are-the-csv-headers-in-outlook-contact-export)

You can use the php function [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to parse the csv to an array.