# Common format CSV for importing contacts?

Tags: csv, crm

Is there some common way qua naming for importing contacts?
I've found out that most applications use the naming format that is used in Outlook. However, I was not able to find any common naming format for importing organizations. [Naming format Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847596/what-are-the-csv-headers-in-outlook-contact-export)

Does anyone know if there is a common naming standard for importing organizations and if there are more common formats for contacts?

Comment: What CRM system are you using?

Comment: We create our own. Question is, what naming standard should it support?